# How do I create a HTML/PHP form where the text input fields are horizontally aligned side by side

Tags: php, html, css

I have successfully made a form however I would like the text input fields to be displayed horizontally next to each other, instead of being stacked on top of eachother.

I have supplied my code and a screenshot of how the form currently looks[current form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRnkw.jpg).. and also a mockup made in Photoshop of how I want the form to look instead.[desired form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdlLA.jpg)

The form has 5 text input fields, and 2 select drop down fields.

I don't need help with the color styling or PHP I can sort that, it's just the actual layout I'm stuck with.

Much appreciated if anyone can help.

```
<?php


// $query = "SELECT 'forename' FROM [Pulse].[dbo].[users]"; // selects the correct table
$query = "SELECT forename FROM [Test].[dbo].[users]"; // selects the correct table
$search = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query); // runs the query and fetches the data
$rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($search); // checks the table has something in it


 ?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:200,300,400,500,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        input[type=text], select, textarea {
            width: 95%;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 3px;
            resize: vertical;
            transition: 0.3s;
            outline: none;
            font-family: Dosis, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            margin: 7px;
        }

        input[type=text]:focus {
            border: 1.25px solid #ea0088;
        }

        select:focus {
            border: 1.25px solid #ea0088;
        }

        label {
            padding: 28px 12px 12px 12px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: Dosis, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: 500;
            color: #999;
        }

        input[type=submit] {
            background-color: #999;
            color: white;
            padding: 12px 50px;
            margin-top: 15px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: right;
            transition: 0.3s;
            font-family: Dosis, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: 500;
            margin-right: 3%;
        }

        input[type=submit]:hover {
            background-color: #ea0088;
        }

        .container {
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 2.5% 20% 0 20%;
        }

        .col-25 {
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
            margin-top: 6px;
        }

        .col-75 {
            float: left;
            width: 75%;
            margin-top: 6px;
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        .scroll {
            overflow-y:visible;
        }

        body {
            background-image: url(proco.jpg);
        }

        /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
                width: 100%;
                margin-top: 0;
            }
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <form action="signin.php" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="* Please complete">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="* Please complete">
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="company">Company</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="company" name="company">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="reg">Car Reg</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="reg" name="reg">
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="badge">Badge</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <select name="badge">
                    <?php
                    for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
                        echo "<option value=" . $i . ">" . $i . "</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>





        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="visiting">Visiting</label>
            </div>
        <div class="col-75">




             <select

                <option selected="selected" class="scroll">Choose one</option>
                <?php
                // A sample product array
                if($rows === true) {
                    //FOR EACH CUSTOMER
                    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($search, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                        // Iterating through the product array
                        foreach ($row as $name) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                }

                ?>
               </select>

            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest using flexbox to create effectively two columns. You can see some examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp Then on a narrow screen it can wrap over to being a single column more easily than something like a table would. This question and your included markup is a bit broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create two separete div's with width:50% and then use display:flex on the form

```html
<?php


// $query = "SELECT 'forename' FROM [Pulse].[dbo].[users]"; // selects the correct table
$query = "SELECT forename FROM [Test].[dbo].[users]"; // selects the correct table
$search = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query); // runs the query and fetches the data
$rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($search); // checks the table has something in it


 ?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:200,300,400,500,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        input[type=text], select, textarea {
            width: 95%;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 3px;
            resize: vertical;
            transition: 0.3s;
            outline: none;
            font-family: Dosis, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            margin: 7px;
        }

        input[type=text]:focus {
            border: 1.25px solid #ea0088;
        }

        select:focus {
            border: 1.25px solid #ea0088;
        }

        label {
            padding: 28px 12px 12px 12px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: Dosis, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: 500;
            color: #999;
        }

        input[type=submit] {
            background-color: #999;
            color: white;
            padding: 12px 50px;
            margin-top: 15px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: right;
            transition: 0.3s;
            font-family: Dosis, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: 500;
            margin-right: 3%;
        }

        input[type=submit]:hover {
            background-color: #ea0088;
        }

        .container {
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 2.5% 20% 0 20%;
        }

        .col-25 {
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
            margin-top: 6px;
        }

        .col-75 {
            float: left;
            width: 75%;
            margin-top: 6px;
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        .scroll {
            overflow-y:visible;
        }

        body {
            background-image: url(proco.jpg);
        }
        
        .left, .right{
          width:50%;
        }
        form{
        display:flex;
        }

        /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
                width: 100%;
                margin-top: 0;
            }
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <form action="signin.php" method="post">
    <div class="left">
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="* Please complete">
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="company">Company</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="company" name="company">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="reg">Car Reg</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="reg" name="reg">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="visiting">Visiting</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">




                <select

                <option selected="selected" class="scroll">Choose one</option>
                <?php
                // A sample product array
                if($rows === true) {
                    //FOR EACH CUSTOMER
                    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($search, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                        // Iterating through the product array
                        foreach ($row as $name) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                }

                ?>
                </select>



            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
    
     <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="* Please complete">
            </div>
        </div>



        



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="badge">Badge</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
                <select name="badge">
                    <?php
                    for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
                        echo "<option value=" . $i . ">" . $i . "</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>





        



        <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
        </div>
    
    </div>

       
    </form>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```